# My Selector select all elements, how select some one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Im making a litle script appear/desappear but my jquery element select all, i think if i make a unique class to all is very classes to use, i preffer one mode of use the **$this** of jquery but i dont know, my code is ruby on rails is this... :

```
<%= link_to_function "Comentar","$(this(div #comment_form)).fadeIn();",:class => 'comentar' %>
```

but select all the posts to appear the box of comment

and my aplication.js to desappear of default:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("div #comment_form").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to affect specific elements on your page,  you'd need to set the id property on each.  So you might have something like this:

```
<% @things.each do |t| %>
  <div id='comment_<%= t.id %>' style='display:none'>
    A Comment 
  </div>
  <%= link_to_function "Comment #{t.id}","$('#comment_#{t.id}').fadeIn();" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks works fine, and im learn the #{lang}, very good thanks man.